# How to fix the Error while running docker container

Tags: docker-compose

Step 1/5 : `FROM python:3.4-alpine`

---> c06adcf62f6e

Step 2/5 : `ADD prince_web/alpine_test/code /home`

> ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: ADD failed: CreateFile
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder370000016\prince_web\alpine_test\code:
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Error explicitly says: Docker can not find the source file which you try to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Use COPY instead of ADD here in this case .

Because it is taking a dynamic path with ADD command which is not present or creates  in  your system .